# PyAudio.Stream on top of portaudio1.9 hangs when reading audio from microphone

Tags: python, portaudio, pyaudio

I'm working on an application that's continuously reading audio from the microphone, built on top of [this SpeechRecognition library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/).

I am consistently reading a chunk of size 1k from the microphone input stream, but it is sometimes blocking for longer than it should take to record the audio. My chunk size/sample rate put 1k frames at about 60ms of audio, so I'm struggling to figure out why the read call would block for >10s at times. It's possible I just don't understand portaudio/pyaudio/computers, and I'd appreciate any insight available from the community.

Environment: I'm seeing this issue both on ubuntu 14.04 LTS and raspbian wheezy/jessie on a raspi 2.